# Can one POST data to an Android Activity with a custom URL scheme?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app which is using a custom scheme as in the link below:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.library.activities.CustomSchemeActivity">            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="custom" android:host="custom.example.com" android:path="/custom" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When a user clicks on a link, say `custom://custom.example.com/custom?parameter=abcd`, CustomSchemeActivity is being launched as expected.

Now, I need to send data to this activity. I can already send it through the URL parameters. I'm curious though, if I POST data to the Intent, would it be possible to read the content? Is it possible to POST data from a server to a handset?

Comment: No. There is no other link between the server and the mobile device other then the URL String. All data should be in there in this case.

Comment: You can bundle extra data in an Intent, but `POST` would not apply as Intents are not HTTP.  An Android app with Internet permission can of course subsequently talk to an HTTP server in just about any normal way.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Stefan. I will have to be content with using HTTP the normal way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra data:

`<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>`

Taken from:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents?hl=es